# CSV export with JPA criteriaQuery performance issue

Tags: performance, spring-boot, export-to-csv, criteria-api

I am trying to export data to csv from my springboot project. I am using simple criteria query and using the getResultStream method like below, but it is taking one minute to export just 1800 rows. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
class SomeService{

    public void searchProductMasterExportList(RequestClass request,HttpServletResponse response){
    try(Stream<SomeModel> exportList = em.createQuery(query).getResultStream()){
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    exportList.forEach((todo -> createCsvLine(todo,out,em)
            ));
            out.flush();

    }
```

---createcsv code is below-it appends the values with the delimeters.
--changed the name of getters to a,b,c,x,etc

```
private void createCsvLine(some parameters){
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    line.append(null==productItemStreamData.x()?"":productItemStreamData.x()).append(",")
                        .append(null==x?"":x).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getPlatform()?"":platformMap.get(productItemStreamData.y())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.y()?"":productItemStreamData.getProductOwner()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getProductStatus()?"":productStatusMap.get(productItemStreamData.a())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.a()?"":productItemStreamData.getDiscountPercentage()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.b()?"":productItemStreamData.b()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.c()?"":productItemStreamData.c()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getPriceStatus()?"":priceStatusMap.get(productItemStreamData.getPriceStatus())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getUnitOfMeasure()?"":productItemStreamData.getUnitOfMeasure()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.d()?"":billingActionMap.get(productItemStreamData.d())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getFrequency()?"":frequencyMap.get(productItemStreamData.getFrequency())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getPriceType()?"":priceTypeMap.get(productItemStreamData.getPriceType())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getClientSegmentName()?"":clientSegmentMap.get(productItemStreamData.getClientSegmentName())).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getPriceTierMin()?"":productItemStreamData.getPriceTierMin()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getPriceTierMax()?"":productItemStreamData.getPriceTierMax()).append(",")
                        .append(null==productItemStreamData.getListPrice()?"":productItemStreamData.getListPrice());

                out.write(line.toString());
                out.write("\n");
                em.detach(productItemStreamData);

    }
```

}

---

now controller is like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/export", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void exportProductItems(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody  ProductItemsSearchRequest request,@RequestHeader (name="ctm-JWT") String jwtToken) throws Exception {
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        service.searchProductMasterExportList(request,response);

    }
```

Comment: You could create a SQL query and directly return the CSV structure. No need for Entites here

Comment: We are creating the where clause dynamically using predicates, and then using getResultStream to fetch the records. Even if i simply write a jpql here and fetch records, it will either be list of Entities, or list of some Objects. I didnt get this-
create a SQL query and directly return the CSV  @SimonMartinelli

Comment: You can write the CSV string in the select clause of your query